ALSA MIDI input Raspberry Pi
I've been trying to use ALSA to connect to my MIDI keyboard, and detect when a certain key is pressed. However, I've been having trouble using my keyboard as an alsa device. There doesn't seem to be issues using "default," but I can't seem to input a new one.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

#define MIDI_DEVICE "default"

int main() {
    int client, port;
    snd_seq_t *seq;
    snd_seq_open(&seq, MIDI_DEVICE, SND_SEQ_OPEN_INPUT, 0);
    client = snd_seq_client_id(seq);
    port = snd_seq_create_simple_port(seq, "My Port",
                                       SND_SEQ_PORT_CAP_READ,
                                       SND_SEQ_PORT_TYPE_APPLICATION);
    snd_seq_event_t *ev;
    
    while (1) {
        snd_seq_event_input(seq, &ev);
        if (ev->type == SND_SEQ_EVENT_NOTEON && ev->data.note.note == 60) {
            printf("Hello World\n");
        }
    }
    
    snd_seq_delete_simple_port(seq, port);
    snd_seq_close(seq);
    
    return 0;
}

I've tried using my Casio as a device (with the id hw:24,0) but I get an error. "unknown parameters hw:24,0"
Does anybody see an issue with this code, or why I won't be able to use the hardware ID? I've also tried using the device name from the /dev/snd folder, being "controlC2" but that one gives me the same error as well.
